# Pack and unpack 64 bit integer

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$packed = pack('i',PHP_INT_MAX);
echo unpack('i', $packed)[1];
```

As result I get `-1`

I'm using `PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2012 01:18:34)`
and my `PHP_INT_MAx` is equal to `9223372036854775807`

Is there any way to work with `pack` function and 64 bit integers?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure this is relevant because I've never used `pack`, but keep in mind that -1 is encoded with all bits set to one, which is also the maximum unsigned integer value encoding. I'd try with a big number slightly smaller than this.

Comment: Since php 5.6.3 you can use q/Q for 64bits numbers, q for signed, Q for unsigned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Save it as two 32Bit instead:

```
$value = PHP_INT_MAX;
$highMap = 0xffffffff00000000; 
$lowMap = 0x00000000ffffffff; 
$higher = ($value & $highMap) >>32; 
$lower = $value & $lowMap; 
$packed = pack('NN', $higher, $lower); 

list($higher, $lower) = array_values(unpack('N2', $packed)); 
$originalValue = $higher << 32 | $lower;
```

- Algorithm taken from: http://php.net/pack#109328
- Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UuLmor